# How to initialize empty Drizzle instance and later provide contracts data

Tags: drizzle

Following Drizzle [documentation](https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle/quickstart), Drizzle instance can only be created with:

```
const drizzle = new Drizzle(options)
```

Where the [`options`](https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle/reference/drizzle-options) is mandatory. And trying to not pass `options` will generate an error:

```
// The following will raise the error:
//   TypeError: Cannot read property 'contracts' of undefined
const drizzle = new Drizzle();
```

And when trying to pass an empty object `{}`, another error will be thrown:

```
// The following will raise the error:
//   TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
const drizzle = new Drizzle({});
```

The idea is that: I want to create the Drizzle object in the constructor and later I will provide the data later [dynamically](https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle/getting-started/contract-interaction#adding-contracts-dynamically):

```
var contractConfig = {
  contractName: "0x066408929e8d5Ed161e9cAA1876b60e1fBB5DB75",
  web3Contract: new web3.eth.Contract(/* ... */)
}
events = ['Mint']

// Using an action
dispatch({type: 'ADD_CONTRACT', drizzle, contractConfig, events, web3})

// Or using the Drizzle context object
this.context.drizzle.addContract(contractConfig, events)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply passing an empty array of contracts inside the type object, will solve the issues:

```
const options = {contracts: []}

this.drizzle = new Drizzle(options);
```

After this, data could be provided dynamically as in: https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle/getting-started/contract-interaction#adding-contracts-dynamically